# Как сформировать условие в хендлере?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

Всем привет. У меня есть две кнопки «**Кнопка-1**» и «**Кнопка-2**», эти кнопки содержат объект **KeyboardButtonRequestChat** с разными критериями. Еще есть 2 обработчика, они получают идентификаторы каналов через Chat_shared после нажатия кнопки. Однако я не понимаю, как создать условие, при котором нажатие «Кнопки-1» вызовет первый обработчик, а нажатие «Кнопки-2» вызовет другой обработчик?

**Кнопки:**

```
    @dp.message(lambda message: message.text == "Buttons")
async def configure_source_channels(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    user_states[user_id] = UserStates.SOURCE_CHANNELS
    keyboard = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=[
        [KeyboardButton(text="button-1", request_chat=KeyboardButtonRequestChat(
            request_id=1,
            user_is_bot=False,
            chat_is_channel=True,
            chat_is_forum=False
        ))],
        [KeyboardButton(text="button-2", request_chat=KeyboardButtonRequestChat(
            request_id=2,
            user_is_bot=True,
            chat_is_channel=False,
            chat_is_forum=False
        ))],
])
```

**Хендлеры:**

```
@dp.message(F.chat)
async def button1(msg: Message, state: FSMContext):
    chat_info = msg.chat_shared.chat_id

@dp.message(F.chat)
async def button2(msg: Message, state: FSMContext):
    chat_info = msg.chat_shared.chat_id
```

Обычно я вставляю условие проверки текста сообщения: message.text == "Button-1" , но в этом случае после нажатия кнопки текст в чат не отправляется.

Буду благодарен за любые идеи.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не до конца понимаю зачем тебе это, но можешь просто фильтровать по shared_chat.request_id

```
@dp.message(F.chat, F.func(lambda msg: msg.chat_shared.request_id == 1))
async def handle_request_chat_button1(msg: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    chat_info = msg.chat_shared.chat_id

@dp.message(F.chat, F.func(lambda msg: msg.chat_shared.request_id == 2))
async def handle_request_chat_button2(msg: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    chat_info = msg.chat_shared.chat_id
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Мне это нужно для того, чтобы при нажатии на первую кнопку, Id канала отправлялся в одну таблицу в БД, а при нажатии на вторую кнопку, в другую таблицу.